# How can I detect the moment a specific DOM node has been downloaded by the browser, while the page is still loading?

Tags: javascript, dom, domcontentloaded

I am writing a user script which needs to access specific DOM nodes on the page.  To reduce latency and page re-layouting, I want to set it to `// @run-at document-start` instead of the usual `// @run-at document-end`, and run my code as soon as the DOM node I need has been downloaded from the server.

If I just wait for a `DOMContentLoaded` event, it will wait for the whole page to be downloaded; this is effectively the same as `// @run-at document-end`.  I want to run my code at an earlier time, right when the browser’s parser encounters the closing tag of the element I want.

Is there a way to accomplish this more elegant than polling `querySelectorAll` from a `MutationObserver` callback?